# Can you do a live deploy on Enterprise apps?

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, ionic3, ios-enterprise

The Enterprise apps are not in the public app stores but in an internal location that only in the organization can use. But the process of installing and authorizing the app is a tedious multi-step for many internal users who are not tech-savvy or just simply do not have time.

I was wondering if there's a Live Deploy that I can use to remotely update the Enterprise mobile apps. I'm currently considering Ionic's Live Deploy but I can't find any information of the possibility with Enterprise apps.

Comment: Best practice is to use an MDM. This can deploy the app to the managed devices, it removes the need for the user to manually trust the enterprise certificate and can also push the updated provisioning profile that is required every year

Comment: HI @Paulw11, can you suggest an MDM? Thanks!

Comment: I can't really recommend one in particular; you need to decide what s right for your organisation; If you have an Office 365 subscription you may have access to Microsoft InTune.  Other popular products are AirWatch and Mobile Iron.  I believe you can manage 100 devices in Meraki Systems Manager for free, so if you have a small organisation that might suit